# xpages dialog title with fa-icon

Tags: xpages

I've asked couple days ago this question [xpages returning class icon in view column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25376711/xpages-returning-class-icon-in-view-column/25376822#25376822) and I understood the fact that the content type must be set to "HTML".

Is it possible to 'concatenate' some fa-icon ( `<span class="fa-save fa" />` ) with the dialog title?

```
        <xe:dialog id="exampleDialog" refreshOnShow="true">
        <span class="fa-save fa" />
        <xe:this.title><![CDATA[#{javascript:"Some string returned."}]]>
        // I couldn't add the <span> tag here...
        </xe:this.title>
        <xe:dialogContent id="dialogContent1">
        ....
```

but the icon is added lower than the title bar.

Comment: I have not tried it myself before but I am sure there's a solution. What have you tried? :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is *indeed* possible to do this:

[image]

You just need to return all of the required HTML in the title property. Here's the example used for the above picture:

```
<xe:dialog id="InputDialog" style="width:200px">
    <xe:this.title><![CDATA[#{javascript:"<span class='fa-save fa' /><i>Testing</i>"}]]></xe:this.title>
    <xe:dialogContent id="dialogContent1">Test content</xe:dialogContent>
</xe:dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

The dialog title area doesn't have a facet, so you can only enter plain text in there. It would only be possible by extending the Extension Library Dialog Control itself to either add a facet or add HTML in the title.